# Problem with Network Type to be used for Java RMI

Tags: java, linux, networking, virtual-machine

I was installing **CentOS Linux distro** in ***VMware Workstation 10*** when I stuck across the issue as to use which **Networking Option** to get my work done. Though I don't know whether it is fit for this site, but I feel someone among you will surely respond positively.

> I will explain this problematic situation in detail. Firstly, I want
>   to get different IP address for my guest OS(CentOS) in VMware with the
>   host OS installed,i.e.,Windows 7 but I want to share the same network
>   on both using ---Mobile Broadband Device MTS data card/Wifi
>   connection(either one working at a time). This I wanna have so that I
>   can apply Java RMI programming on Server(Windows 7) and Client(CentOS)
>   or vice-versa! So, I am confused as to go through which option. Please
>   correct my mistaken assumptions/give any feedback OR anything helpful
>   for me. I'll be really thankful for gaining the insight.

[image: Network_Type]

Please consider the case that I want to achieve Message Passing in Host(Windows) and Guest(CentOS) or vice-versa using Java RMI. Hence, I think the networking is an important case(might be inappropriate assumption),though it involves the hostname only of the Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the help text on the vmware dialog box is pretty self explanatory.

I don't know how your data card gets/assigns ip address,I guess you do not have any control over the number of ip address you get assigned.

Assuming you do not have any dhcp servers configured and you will only get a single IP from your data card.I would suggest going with the NAT.So what will happen when you configure NAT is your host machine (windows) will create same number virtual interface named something like vmnet* as the number interfaces in your guest(centos). you can then manually configure the interface address in guest and hosts to be in  the same network.This will act like a small development network,and when you go to internet from your guest system your local test network ip address will be translated to an external ip (Vmware does this under the hood for you).

One disadvantage of this mode is that you cannot reach your guest machine from a remote location say for eg if you need to ssh to your guest machine from your home unless you do some sort of port forwarding in your host machine.I do not know how to do that in a windows box.

Comment: I should clearly state that What I finally want is different IP-Addresses on host and guest machines.So,as per you NAT should do for me!

Comment: yes, NAT should be fine as long as  you do not want to access the guest from outside.

Comment: And,what about the latter case---If I want to access the guest from outside,say different PC??

Comment: to access the guest from outside the easiest way will be to use bridged mode if you data card can supply two ip addresses.If not there might be a way to port forward specific ports to a different machine(you have to do it in you windows box,I highly doubt it exist in windows but I might be wrong).so my guess is you cannot do this with a data card, you might have to move to a router based gateway for your internet which can supply multiple ip addresses.